# UIFont fontWithSize: changes the fontName

Tags: ios, objective-c, uifont

if I'm trying to change the size of `UIFont` it changes the font name (ad type).
before:
`font.fontName` is equal to `@".SFUIText-Regular"`

**execute this:**
`font = [font fontWithSize:size];`

after:
`font.fontName` is equal to `@".SFUIDisplay-Regular"`

Why? How to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `[UIFont systemFontOfSize:36]` or `[UIFont fontWithName:@"SFUIDisplay-Regular" size:36]`

This link may help: [only change font size (and not font name)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19070385/only-change-font-size-and-not-font-name/19070942#19070942)

Comment: I just want to change the size of the font. With the same other parameters.

Comment: @Patrik. Yes. I think your link containts the only code to use. this is the clue.

Comment: Good luck :) :) :)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to avoid this? The operating system decided that the font closest to ".SFUIText-Regular" in the size you want is a font named ".SFUIDisplay-Regular". That's entirely within the rules.

Live with it.

Comment: I'd like to measure the symbols using the CoreText libraries. These fonts give me different measured width values.

Answer (score 1):

You can go for this

```
label.font = [label.font fontWithSize:50];
```

Comment: Nope. I said, that it doesn't work. It changes the font.

Comment: It never changes the font ... i have used it
please check it once